# Node.js xmpp client gets "BAD_REGISTRATION" error as message response

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

What could possibly be wrong with this code? I'm trying to send push notification to my mobile device. No luck so far.. Made a little test with php and using GCM HTTP protocol to understand if my API's and passwords are correct - everything worked like a charm.. Here's my code snippet which is not working.

```
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp-client');
var ltx = require('ltx');

var options = {
  jid: 'xxxxxxxxxxx@gcm.googleapis.com',
  password: 'AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  port: 5235,
  host: 'gcm.googleapis.com',
  legacySSL: true,
  preferredSaslMechanism: true
};

var xmppClient = new xmpp.Client(options);
xmppClient.connection.socket.setTimeout(0);
xmppClient.connection.socket.setKeepAlive(true, 10000);
xmppClient.on('online', function() {
  var receiver = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-GnbkL2e5UlsS4utMw9rLTFrcsrhqxeH8xvzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
  /*var rawmsg = '<message id=""><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"to":"' + receiver + '", "message_id":"m-xxxx123", "data": {"hello":"world"}, "time_to_live":600, "delay_while_idle": true, "delivery_receipt_requested": true }</gcm></message>';
  var msg = ltx.parse(rawmsg);*/

  var msg = new xmpp.Element('message', {id: ''}).c('gcm', {xmlns: 'google:mobile:data'}).t(JSON.stringify({
    to: receiver,
    message_id: 'm-xxxx123',
    time_to_live: 600,
    delay_while_idle: true,
    delivery_receipt_requested: true
  }));
  xmppClient.send(msg);
  ............
  ............
}
```

And this is what comes back on 'stanza's event as a response.

```
........","message_id":"m-xxxx123","error":"BAD_REGISTRATION","error_description":""}' ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are the possible causes of your error according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#error-codes).

> **Invalid Registration Token**
>
> Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with GCM. Do not truncate or add additional characters.
>
> **Mismatched Sender**
>
> A registration token is tied to a certain group of senders. When a client app registers for GCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work.